# What is the name of the manga which depicts Hitler as a Super Aryan?

Tags: mudazumo-naki-kaikaku

I've come across the following picture, can anyone please tell me what's the manga name?

[image: Over 9000!!!]

Comment: Godwin's law finally reaches Dragonball Z...or maybe this is a new law that everything will eventuality parody Dragonball Z

Comment: @Memor-X I had never heard of Godwin's law, but this reminded me greatly of the match between Germany and the USA. The amount of Nazi related messages was too damn high.

Comment: @PeterRaeves [Godwin's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godwin%27s_law) = "*As an online discussion grows longer, the probability of a comparison involving Nazis or Hitler approaches 1*", though i haven't read the manga it looks that "Super Aryan" is a parody of "Super Saiyan" and looking at the image very much like Dragoinball Z (hair going blonde as described, the left frame reminiscent of Feeza's or Vageta's reaction to Goku) so as discussions of Dragonball Z continued the likelihood of a comparison to Nazi's was growing more likely, and now we have it, Super Saiyan 2 Hitler

Comment: @Memor-X yeah i got it the first time u said it lol. Maybe we should call the increasing probability of a manga parodying DBZ Memor-x' law from now on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called [Mudazumo Naki Kaikaku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mudazumo_Naki_Kaikaku). The characters are all based off of real-life politicians like George Bush, Kim Jong Il, Mao, Pol Pot, Putin, and of course, many from Nazi Germany, and they play Mahjong together in this manga. It was also adapted into an anime series.

[image]

Comment: I'll add that although this sounds like it's totally awesome, it really is kind of a let down. Especially the 3 episode OVA.